# Better way to binarize an image

Tags: image-processing

I have an image:

```
pic = Import[
  "http://note.youdao.com/yws/public/resource/\
2c5a562224240edcf1631fcd39810f56/55FA538207424C0A98AB548724994AE1"]
```

> [image: enter link description here]

that I want to binarize. When I try to do it in *Mathematica*, the results is 
[image]

My code is

```
bin = MorphologicalBinarize[pic // ColorNegate, {0.4, 0.6}]
```

I tried this many times. The result was always bad. I want to binarize the image so I can count the lattice (including that adjacent to the border). Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you try reposting your first image to imgur?

Comment: From the looks of your output image (please repost the original though) you should try [`LocalAdaptiveBinarize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LocalAdaptiveBinarize.html).

Comment: @J.M. Can I repost my picture to imgur when I'm commenting?

Comment: Sure, why not?${}$

Comment: How to do it?Or where is the tutorial?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As suggested by Rahul, `LocalAdaptiveBinarize` is your friend:

```
LocalAdaptiveBinarize[pic, 15]
```

[image]

In order to count things, you can use the `MorphologicalComponents` command. Here we colorize it to get a visualization of how well the morphological processing segments the data:

```
MorphologicalComponents[LocalAdaptiveBinarize[pic, 15]] // Colorize
```

[image]

Of course, [MorphologicalComponents](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MorphologicalComponents.html) is very versatile and can help gather statistics about your image and the segmentation.

Comment: +1, I would also suggest a bigger radius so you don't get the extra noise in the middle of the pieces.